# Search data from Outlook in the Excel spreadsheet, then copy the finded cell (dorm cell next to the one found here)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to create a vba script which will create a mail in Outlook to finded addresses(from excel). Searching should be based on selected mail in outlook(specific string - ID). I know how to create email in vba script , but i dont know how to open and search data in excel from outlook vba.
Some code below.

```vb
Sub SMSKI()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objFwd As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strAddr As String
    Dim xlApp As Object 
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook 
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet 
    On Error Resume Next
    Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

     Dim rng1 As Range
     Dim strSearch As String



    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
    Set objOL = Application
    Set objItem = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)


    With xlApp 
       .Visible = True 
       .EnableEvents = False 
     End With 

     strFile = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\SMS.xlsx"  'Put your file path.

    Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(strFile, , False, , , , , , , True) 
    Set sourceWH = sourceWB.Worksheets("SalesForm") 
    sourceWB.Activate 


    If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
        strAddr = objItem.Body
        If strAddr <> "" Then
            ' Set objFwd = objItem.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            ' objFwd.To = strAddr


            vText = Split(strAddr, Chr(13))
            strAddr = Right(Left(vText(0), 9), 8)
            strAddr = Left(strAddr, Len(strAddr) - 8)
            vText = Split(strAddr, " ")
            vText = Split(strAddr, Chr(58))
            strSearch = Right(Left(vText(0), 9), 8)
            myItem.Subject = Right(Left(vText(0), 9), 8)
            Set rng1 = Range("C:C").Find(strSearch, , sourceWB.xlValues, sourceWB.xlWhole)
            myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "mail@bla.com"
            myItem.To = ?
            myItem.Cc = ""
            'myItem.Subject = FindWord(strAddr, 1)
            ' objFwd.Sent = False
            myItem.Display
            ' objFwd.Body = ""




            myItem.HTMLBody = "reboot"

        Else
            MsgBox "Could not extract address from message."
        End If
    End If
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objFwd = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Modified code
This code open SMS.xlsx but dont search a specific id from mail.(and not copy obviously)
How can I change this code to achieve what i want?**

```vb
Option Explicit








Sub TestGetValueFromExcel()

  Dim ReturnedValue As String
  Dim SearchValue As Variant
  Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objFwd As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strAddr As String
    Dim vText As Variant
    Dim myItem As Object
      Dim WbkSrc As Workbook
  Dim WshtSrc As Worksheet
      Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application

    On Error Resume Next
    Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set objOL = Application
    Set objItem = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)




  With xlApp
    .Visible = True   ' Slows execution but helpful during debugging
    .EnableEvents = False
    Set WbkSrc = .Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\SMS.xlsx")
  End With


 With WbkSrc
    Set WshtSrc = .Worksheets("SalesForm")
  End With




 If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
        strAddr = objItem.Body
        If strAddr <> "" Then
            ' Set objFwd = objItem.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            ' objFwd.To = strAddr
            vText = Split(strAddr, Chr(13))
            strAddr = vText(2)
            strAddr = Left(strAddr, Len(strAddr) - 8)
            vText = Split(strAddr, Chr(58))
            myItem.Subject = Right(Left(vText(0), 9), 8)


            SearchValue = Right(Left(vText(0), 9), 8)


   ReturnedValue = GetValueFromExcel(WshtSrc, CStr(SearchValue))


            myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "mateusz.cymerman@snt.pl"
            myItem.To = ReturnedValue
            myItem.CC = ""

            myItem.Display





            myItem.HTMLBody = "reboot"



  WbkSrc.Close SaveChanges:=False
  Set WbkSrc = Nothing

 Else
        MsgBox "Nothing Selected."
    End If


    With xlApp
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Quit
  End With

  Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objFwd = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing

    End If

End Sub
Function GetValueFromExcel(ByRef Wsht As Worksheet, ByVal SearchValue As String) As String

  Dim Rng As Range

  With Wsht

    Set Rng = .Columns("B").Find(What:=SearchValue, After:=.Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                                 SearchFormat:=False)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      ' SearchValue not found
      GetValueFromExcel = ""
    Else
      ' Return value in column C of row containing SearchValue
      GetValueFromExcel = .cells(Rng.Row, "C")
    End If

  End With

End Function
```

[image: excel SMS.xlsx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not like to criticise someone's English when I have long since forgotten the little French and Russian I once knew.  I believe “finded” should be “found”; the verb “find” is one many irregular verbs.  I do not know what “dorm” means.

Your code decodes the text body of an email selected using Explorer.  This means the user must select an email before running this email.  That email contains strings which you expect to find in the workbook.  Without understanding the reason for this approach, I cannot offer any advice but this seems very strange to me.

You do not say why you are searching the worksheet “SalesForm” or what you will do when you find the search value.  I have returned the value from column D of the row containing the search value.  You can replace “D” with the letter or number for some other column.  If your requirement is more complex, you will have to provide an explanation of what you seek.

I have provided a function “GetValueFromExcel” and a routine to show how to use it.  You can copy my function and call it from your code or you can study how my code works and build your own version.

You have:

```
Dim xlApp As Object 
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

I have:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
```

The “New” keyword and “Excel.Application” to identify the object I want means I do not need the CreateObject statement.  I have read that your method is marginally more efficient than mine but you will often see this different approach.

You have:

```
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objItem As Object
Set objItem = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
```

You are within Outlook so you do not need `objOL`.  This is the same as:

```
Dim objItem As Object
Set objItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
```

Used as you have, `On Error Resume Next` means “do not tell me about any errors because I like mysterious failures.  Please do not use this statement unless you know you need it and you know how to use it correctly.

You have:

```
strFile = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\SMS.xlsx"  'Put your file path.
Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(strFile, , False, , , , , , , True)
```

I have:

```
With xlApp
  Set WbkSrc = .Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\SMS.xlsx")
End With
```

`Environ("UserProfile")` returns “C:\Users\xxxx” where “xxxx” is the current user.  If you share this macro with a colleague, the macro will adjust to the new user without needing any changes.

I have included the path and file name within the call of Workbooks.Open to show it is possible.

You have specified the parameters for Workbooks.Open by their position.  I will do this when it is obvious what the parameters are but I do not like counting down commas to work out what the False and True mean.  `FileName:=` makes it absolutely clear what this parameter is.  You do not appear to want to amend this workbook so I do not see the value of `ReadOnly:=False`.  I do not believe `Editable:=True` is relevant.

`sourceWB.Activate` is not necessary.

My code is below.  Copy it to a module within your Outlook installation and try it out before deciding how to add it to your routine.  To test my code, I created a workbook named “SMS.xlsx” on my desktop, placed search values such as “Aaaaa” in column C and placed return values in column D.

Macro “GetValueFromExcel” searches column C of a referenced worksheet for a specified search value.  It returns the value from column D if the search value is found and the empty string if the search value is not found.

Macro “TestGetValueFromExcel” demonstrates how to use “GetValueFromExcel”.  You will need to replace `SearchValues = VBA.Array("Aaaaa", "Bbbbb", "Fffff", "Hhhhh")`.  Values "Aaaaa", "Bbbbb" and "Fffff" appear in my column C.  Value "Fffff" does not appear in my column C.  Replace my values with values from your column C.

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestGetValueFromExcel()

  Dim ReturnedValue As String
  Dim SearchValue As Variant
  Dim SearchValues As Variant
  Dim WbkSrc As Workbook
  Dim WshtSrc As Worksheet
  Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application

  SearchValues = VBA.Array("Aaaaa", "Bbbbb", "Fffff", "Hhhhh")

  With xlApp
    .Visible = True   ' Slows execution but helpful during debugging
    .EnableEvents = False
    Set WbkSrc = .Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\SMS.xlsx")
  End With
  With WbkSrc
    Set WshtSrc = .Worksheets("SalesForm")
  End With

  For Each SearchValue In SearchValues
    ReturnedValue = GetValueFromExcel(WshtSrc, CStr(SearchValue))
    If ReturnedValue = "" Then
      Debug.Print """" & SearchValue & """ not found"
    Else
      Debug.Print """" & SearchValue & """ returned """ & ReturnedValue & """"
    End If
  Next

  WbkSrc.Close SaveChanges:=False
  Set WbkSrc = Nothing
  With xlApp
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Quit
  End With
  Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Update: Diagnostic version of `GetValueFromExcel` plus `DsplInHex`, `PadL` and `PadR`**

```
Function GetValueFromExcel(ByRef Wsht As Worksheet, ByVal SearchValue As String) As String

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long

  With Wsht

    Set Rng = .Columns("B").Find(What:=SearchValue, After:=.Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                                 SearchFormat:=False)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      ' SearchValue not found
      Debug.Print "SearchValue not found"
      RowLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
      For RowCrnt = 2 To RowLast
        Debug.Print Wsht.Name & ".Cells(" & RowCrnt & ",B):"
        Call DsplInHex(.Cells(RowCrnt, "B").Value)
      Next
      Debug.Print "SearchValue:"
      Call DsplInHex(SearchValue)
      GetValueFromExcel = ""
    Else
      ' Return value in column D of row containing SearchValue
      GetValueFromExcel = .Cells(Rng.Row, "C")
    End If

  End With

End Function
Public Sub DsplInHex(Stg As String)

  ' Display Stg in text and hex-digit format.

  ' 19Apr16  Latest date on which it might have been coded.
  ' Pre-     / Hex-digit format only as single row with space between
  ' 17Aug17  \ each character and no padding of short hex values.
  ' 17Aug17  Amended to display text value of characters as well as hex values
  '          and for fixed width display with position within string upto 999.

  Dim ChrGt255 As Boolean
  Dim ChrLng As Long
  Dim ChrStr As String
  Dim LineHex As String
  Dim LineTxt As String
  Dim PadLen As Long
  Dim Pos As Long

  ' Check for (1) all characters at most two hex-digits or (2) at least
  ' one character being more than two hex-digits
  ChrGt255 = False
  For Pos = 1 To Len(Stg)
    If AscW(Mid(Stg, Pos, 1)) > 255 Then
      ChrGt255 = True
    End If
  Next

  If ChrGt255 Then
    ' Need upto four hex-digits per character
    PadLen = 4
  Else
    ' Need at most two hex-digits per character
    PadLen = 2
  End If

  LineHex = "   |"
  LineTxt = "---|"
  For Pos = 0 To 9
    LineHex = LineHex & " " & PadL(Chr$(Asc("0") + Pos), PadLen)
  Next
  LineTxt = PadR(LineTxt, Len(LineHex), "-")

  For Pos = 0 To Len(Stg) - 1
    If Pos Mod 10 = 0 Then
      Debug.Print LineHex    ' Output heading or previous line
      Debug.Print LineTxt
      ' Initialise next line
      LineHex = PadL(Format(Pos, "###"), 3, "0") & "|" ' Position of first character on line
      LineTxt = "   |"
    End If
    ChrStr = Mid(Stg, Pos + 1, 1)
    ChrLng = AscW(ChrStr)
    If ChrLng < 0 Then
      ' Character is &H8000& or above and the top bit is negative
      ChrLng = ChrLng + 65536
    End If

    If ChrLng < 32 Or (ChrLng >= 127 And ChrLng < 160) Then
      ' Control character (non-display)
      ChrStr = "nd"
    End If
    LineHex = LineHex & " " & PadL(Hex(ChrLng), PadLen)
    LineTxt = LineTxt & " " & PadL(ChrStr, PadLen)
  Next
  Debug.Print LineHex    ' Output final line
  Debug.Print LineTxt

End Sub
Public Function PadL(ByVal Str As String, ByVal PadLen As Long, _
                     Optional ByVal PadChr As String = " ") As String

  ' Pad Str with leading PadChr to give a total length of PadLen
  ' If the length of Str exceeds PadLen, Str will not be truncated

  '   Sep15 Coded
  ' 20Dec15 Added code so overlength strings are not truncated
  ' 10Jun16 Added PadChr so could pad with characters other than space

  If Len(Str) >= PadLen Then
    ' Do not truncate over length strings
    PadL = Str
  Else
    PadL = Right$(String(PadLen, PadChr) & Str, PadLen)
  End If

End Function
Public Function PadR(ByVal Str As String, ByVal PadLen As Long, _
                     Optional ByVal PadChr As String = " ") As String

  ' Pad Str with trailing PadChr to give a total length of PadLen
  ' If the length of Str exceeds PadLen, Str will not be truncated

  '   Nov15 Coded
  ' 15Sep16 Added PadChr so could pad with characters other than space

  If Len(Str) >= PadLen Then
    ' Do not truncate over length strings
    PadR = Str
  Else
    PadR = Left$(Str & String(PadLen, PadChr), PadLen)
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's almost this what i wanted. Im gonna do few changes and i will share it on this site.

Comment: I want the script to create the mail itself.
It has to look for an id from the selected email in excel SMS.
It has to look in this excel in column B and copy the column C next to B.
The copied column C contains e-mails and for this mails should be created new email. I hope now I explained better what i want to achive.

Comment: @MateuszCym  I do not understand.  Your question implies you know how to create the email and how to extract the search value from the selected email.  You asked about searching a worksheet.  I have provided a routine that searches a worksheet and returns a value.  You have incorporated my routine into your code.  What is not working?

Comment: It's creating a new email, but not copy this data from excel SMS. I don't know why. Sorry for the problem , I think I'm close but still I can't get this result which I would like to have.

Comment: You extract the required value into `ReturnedValue` but do not copy that value into the email.  Where do you want it to go?

Comment: myItem.To  <—- destination of copied object

Comment: You have added `myItem.To = GetValueFromExcel(WbkSrc, SearchValue)` to your code.  Did that have the effect you want?  You should check `ReturnValue <> ""` to ensure the search was successful and replace `myItem.To = GetValueFromExcel(WbkSrc, SearchValue)` by `myItem.To = RerturnValue` if it is successful.  Have you checked that the correct SearchValue is extracted from the selected email?

Comment: Yes correct SearchValue is extracted but it's still not working ;/

Comment: I think its not copy this data from excel.

Comment: @MateuszCym In my `GetValueFromExcel`, the first parameter is a worksheet.  You have changed my `ByRef Wsht As Worksheet` to `ByRef WbkSrc As Worksheet`.  In your call of `GetValueFromExcel`, the first parameter is a workbook.  I do not understand why this did not result in a compile-time error.  Look at how I call `GetValueFromExcel`.

Comment: i made it some changes (u can check this changes upper).

Comment: But still this script only opening excel and do not copy data.I have null in ReturnedValue variable

Comment: @MateuszCym  I do not know how I can help.  As far as I can see, you have undone the harmful changes.  I do not know the value of SearchValue and I do not know the contents of column B of worksheet “SalesForm” of workbook “SMS.xlsx.”  If ReturnedValue is empty, macro `GetValueFromExcel` failed to find SearchValue within column “B”.  You need to investigate why.  I would use F8 to single step through the call of `GetValueFromExcel`.  What is the value of SearchValue?  Is this value in column “B”?

Comment: Exactly SearchValue  is in column B. And i want to copy value in C column to variable (value in column c of row containing SearchValue in B column).

Comment: I added how excel looks. Look up.

Comment: @MateuszCym  Seeing the workbook does not help because I cannot diagnose the problem for you.  The most likely explanation is that `SearchValue` is slightly different from the value in the workbook that it should match.  For example, a trailing space or linefeed will not be easy to see but will defeat `Find`.  I have updated my answer with a new version of `GetValueFromExcel` and new macros `DsplInHex`, `PadL` and `PadR`.  Together they output diagnostic information which should help.